# How php memory releasing depends on hardware?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, curl

On pc PHP don't return to OS memory allocated to curl channels.

It can be checked by this script:

```
<?php

$rss_cmd = " ps -o rss= -p ".posix_getpid();

echo "start: ".exec($rss_cmd).PHP_EOL;

$chs=[];

for ($i=0; $i<50000; $i++) {
    $chs[]=curl_init();
}

echo "after init channels: ".exec($rss_cmd).PHP_EOL;


foreach ($chs as $ch) {
    curl_close($ch);
}

echo "after close channels: ".exec($rss_cmd).PHP_EOL;


$chs=null;
unset($chs);

echo "after unset channels: ".exec($rss_cmd).PHP_EOL;


gc_collect_cycles();

echo "after init gc: ".exec($rss_cmd).PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
start: 25104
after init channels: 1191560
after close channels: 1193280
after unset channels: 1191236
after init gc: 1191236
```

As we can see, memory still be allocated after closing curl channels.

But when i run this script on any other computer i have another result:

```
start: 20060
after init channels: 1781244
after close channels: 69820
after unset channels: 67772
after init gc: 67772
```

What is the reason for this difference?

PS
i check it with severals os and php versions: ubuntu server 16.04, ubuntu desktop 16.04, ubuntu 17.10, Mac OS X, php 7.0, php 7.1, php 7.2, libcurl 7.55, libcurl 7.47

Answer (score 0):

This has less to do with PHP and more to do with how the OS manages memory it assigns to applications.

If you call PHP's [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/memory_get_usage) after each of your `echo` calls, you will see that PHP's memory usage is going down (and therefore freeing up resources internally).

The kernel won't necessarily re-claim that previously allocated memory for other applications right away unless it really needs it.

Even when a program `free()`s memory it has allocated, the OS may choose to leave the memory allocated to the program in case it allocates more memory later, in which case it just gives it back the previous real memory addresses for use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
But i'm still confused - why absolutly identical os and soft on group of other pc's freeing memory immediately and only on one pc it waits a convenient moment (really it's going to swap and crash later)?